# ClearCase - How to enable "Evil Twin Detection"

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am creating new VOBs to replace some that are 10+ years old that we were becoming a problem to use anymore. We upgraded to ClearCase 8 a while ago, and will be staying at this version indefinitely. I know that a feature was made available (finally) to detect and find evil twins, but I can't find how to enable it. I see in the VOB description that it says "evil twin detection: disabled". I have search for the switch, but cannot find information on it.

We are running ClearCase UCM 8.0.14 on an all Windows platform

I have triggers for preventing the creation of evil twins, but since there is a built in way of managing these I would rather use that.

Comment: Since you mentioned creating new VOBs, you may want to use - flevel 7 in your mkvob command to avoid automatically creating an ACL-enabled VOB. Nothing wrong with ACLs, but the defaults are more strict than you may expect.

Also, 8.0.1.x has been out of support since April 30th. If you are not willing to pay the "support extension" surcharge (quotes are often described as "punitive"), you should move to 9.0.1.x.

Answer (score 1):

[Evil twins](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21125072) (two elements of the same name that have been created in different versions of the same directory element) has [some pre-requisites](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21567310):

> - VOB requires schema 80 and feature level 7
> - VOB server requires 8.0 or later
> - Clients must be at 8.0 or later to detect and prevent evil twins from being created

So check your [VOB feature level](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119269), with at least [`cleartool describe -l vob:\avob`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm): the output will include it.